# best way to use django rest framework instead of django orm

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using `django-rest-framework` for api for my webapp. Is it good to use django rest framework in place of `default ORM provided by django`? I have refered to this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/277701/why-do-people-do-rest-apis-instead-of-dbals) and still confused. As drf-api requires classes to be created and I think its better to use that code for handling objects since I can reuse code.

#### urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
```

#### views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

#### serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
```

How can I handle objects the `crud` way in `views.py` using django rest framework?

Comment: No, I don't think you should be using DRF on the server side if you have access to the model. Or is this not what you're asking?

Comment: @ArnarYngvason, your comment fits as answer to the first part of my question. Why is it bad to use `drf` instead of `django orm`? I have updated this question. Can you please refer to the link in updated question?

Answer (score 3):

There are two layers here: The `Model` and the `Model Serializer`; the `Model` being the bottom layer.

- When you need to interact with the database within your Django Application you should use the `Model`.
- When you need to interact with the database from the client, you can either...

  - **A:** create a `view` which, works in the traditional way of rendering the content on the server side and then send back a `POST` request from the client to the view, if you want to edit (i.e. `django-forms`) , or...
  - **B:** Setup a `REST API` that lets you fetch and update your database content via `AJAX` request. This is the purpose of an `API`.
- If you have any logic that has to run regardless of whether you're dealing with the `Model` or the `Model Serializer`, then it should be implemented on the bottom layer, i.e. the `Model`.

The reason we often today use an `API` even though we're not building an external application is that it allows for more interactive and faster user interfaces.
Most popular front-end frameworks today, (for example [`angularjs`](https://angularjs.org/)), are built around the concept of using an `API`.

Comment: Do an indirection (in this case, I think the REST Api layer) as mentioned in `programmers.stackexchange` post really helps with security as only the states are transferred by REST api?

Comment: Security is implemented in the `view` in any case (be it the `ModelViewSet` or a traditional django view). Neither the `model` or the `serializer` are responsible for security. You can decide to only ever interact with the database through the API [from the client], but the reasons for that should not be security, but rather software architecture.

Comment: I think you might be interpreting too much from that post you referred to. Don't over complicate things. Just use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Just to be clear though: Having an API as opposed to, for example, exposing the database, for querying, to the client will of course allow you to have more access control. In short; if you want an external client to be able to interact with the database, then you should use an API.

Comment: Yes you are right I was confused a bit. And about `if you want an external client to be able to interact with the database, then you should use an API` ,its okay. I know it. But is there any advantage in using Api instead of django ORM in webapp? I am using django rest framework and I think `drf api` uses django orm at some stage to perform crud operations.

Comment: No, there is no advantage to using the API when you have access to the ORM. Yes, DRF is layered on top of the Django ORM, but it's specific purpose is to create an API.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a possible scenario to Arnar Yngvason's excellent answer.

- C: You can use DRF's viewset from your view code.

  ```
   review_metas_response = ReviewMetaViewSet.as_view({
       'get': 'user_visit_list'
   })(request, format="json", limit=REVIEW_META_NUM)
  ```
- D: You can use DRF's serializer from your view code.

  ```
   review_meta = ReviewMeta.objects.get(id=review_meta_id)
   serializer = ReviewMetaSerializer(review_meta, context=context)
  ```

I tend to make `model` thick (many methods) and make DRF `serializer & viewset` thick and make views thin.